# WinForm DateTimePicker blues. Is it me?

Tags: winforms, datetimepicker

I want to be able to accept a NULL date using the DateTimePicker control.

The "Checked" property appears to be intended to specify whether the control "holds a date" or now. However, when "unchecked", the date still appears, though it appears disabled. To me, this is distracting. If the intent of the unchecked checkbox is to indicate that there is no date value, why is there ANY date value disable or otherwise that appears in the textbox? It seems to me that if the control is unchecked, the textbox should be EMPTY and that seeing a dimmed date value when the user really wants "no value" is distracting.

If the user toggled the checkbox on, then I would like the ability to place a default value into the textbox.

I am considering creating a usercontrol that toggles between a dateTimePicker control and a textBox, but I hate to go through this trouble.

I tried looking a Telerik's DateTimePicker but trying to get decent null handling functionality out of that control seems worse.  I'd love to see a working example of what one of you think is a user-friendly code example with either the std MS or Telerik DateTimePicker control that accepts null input.

I've looked at a few opensource controls, but every time they fix one issue, they introduce others.

EDIT:

See my answer below. It seems to work fine, now I just want to make it part of every DateTimePicker's behavior.

Comment: I can't help but mention moving to WPF if you have the option; these are the types of issues that can be easily fixed within WPF versus WinForms.

Comment: Just for the record, it's not you. The `DateTimePicker` control gives *everyone* the blues.

Comment: Thanks. The real surprising thing is that Telerik, a company known for great controls, seemed even worse in this regard. I'd rather use their control, because it is obviously more highly functional, but I was wasting too much time just trying to get it to do what the MS control did. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit tricky to get right.  This looked good:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyDateTimePicker
    Inherits DateTimePicker
    Implements ISupportInitialize

    Public Sub New()
        Me.ShowCheckBox = True
        Me.NullDate = True
    End Sub

    Private CustomFormatBacking As String = ""
    Private FormatBacking As DateTimePickerFormat = DateTimePickerFormat.Long

    <DefaultValue(True)> _
    <Bindable(True)> _
    Public Property NullDate() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Not Me.Checked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.Checked = Not value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue("")> _
    <Localizable(True)> _
    <RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)> _
    Public Shadows Property CustomFormat() As String
        Get
            Return CustomFormatBacking
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            CustomFormatBacking = value
            If DesignMode Or Not NullDate Then MyBase.CustomFormat = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)> _
    Public Shadows Property Format() As DateTimePickerFormat
        Get
            Return FormatBacking
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTimePickerFormat)
            FormatBacking = value
            If DesignMode Or Not NullDate Then MyBase.Format = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue(true)> _
    <Bindable(True)> _
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> _
    Public Shadows Property Checked() As Boolean
        Get
            Return MyBase.Checked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.Checked = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub updateNullState()
        If NullDate and Not DesignMode Then
            MyBase.CustomFormat = " "
            MyBase.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        Else
            MyBase.CustomFormat = CustomFormatBacking
            MyBase.Format = FormatBacking
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeginInit() Implements System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.BeginInit
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndInit() Implements System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit
        updateNullState()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal eventargs As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)
        updateNullState()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Not helpful, how extraordinary :/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Well, actually I'm smart enough to understand, but my users had a problem.

I solved by removing the checkbox, and adding 2 radio buttons. Looks something like this now:

(using pseudo UI)

```
O No value entered
O | 1/1/2010   |V|
```

The top radiobutton is checked when there is no value (null), the bottom one when there is a value. I do not hide, or disable the bottom control, and users seem to understand.

The downside is, that it takes a lot more space.

PS: Next thing users will complain about is using the scroll-wheel when a combo-box has focus.

Comment: Very non standard and unnecessary overhead of additional controls that shouldn't be needed. I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: Standards are important to users, that's why every user has its own standards.

Answer (score 1):

Klugey, but it seems to get the job done. If the checkbox is not checked, assume a NULL value.

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged


    If DateTimePicker1.Checked Then
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short 'Or whatever the original format was
    Else
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "
    End If

End Sub
```

OK, the next question...How do I roll this behavior into a subclassed DateTimePicker? What I want to do is to capture the original values of the Format and CustomFormat properties as set in the Properties window. But, this clearly isn't the way to do it.

Here's my feeble attempt:

```
Public Class NullableDateTimePicker

    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Private _OriginalFormat As DateTimePickerFormat
    Private _OriginalCustomerFormat As String

    Private Sub NullableDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ValueChanged

        If Me.Checked Then
            Me.Format = _OriginalFormat
            Me.CustomFormat = _OriginalCustomerFormat
        Else
            Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            Me.CustomFormat = " "
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _DP_FormatChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Static Count As Integer

        If Count = 0 Then
            _OriginalFormat = Me.Format
            _OriginalCustomerFormat = Me.CustomFormat
        End If

        Count += 1

    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler MyBase.FormatChanged, AddressOf _DP_FormatChanged
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is many years after your initial question but here's a subclass of the Telerik RadDateTimePicker that does what you were asking for:

```
Imports Telerik.WinControls.UI

Public Class DateTimePickerWithNull
    Inherits Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDateTimePicker

    Private ReadOnly _calendar As RadCalendar

    Sub New()
        Dim calendarBehavior As RadDateTimePickerCalendar = Me.DateTimePickerElement.GetCurrentBehavior()
        calendarBehavior.DropDownMinSize = New Size(220, 150)

        _calendar = calendarBehavior.Calendar
        _calendar.ShowFooter = True

        AddHandler _calendar.ClearButton.Click, AddressOf ClearButton_Click
        AddHandler _calendar.TodayButton.Click, AddressOf TodayButton_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Do this to put the calendar away
        _calendar.SelectedDate = _calendar.FocusedDate

        'Then clear
        Me.SetToNullValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TodayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        _calendar.SelectedDate = _calendar.FocusedDate
    End Sub

End Class
```

To get the value of the picker:

```
If DateTimePicker1.Value.Date = DateTimePicker1.NullDate Then
    Label1.Text = "Null"
Else
    Label1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString
End If
```